# Sitecore Multiple Sites - Using Wildcards With hostName Attribute

Tags: sitecore

I'm having an issue with getting a site set up in the web.config file for a Sitecore site.  Specifically I can't figure how to use the hostName property to capture the "www" subdomain for a domain (e.g. www.mydomain.com) as well as no specified subdomain (e.g. mydomain.com).

I've experimented a little and found that I can do something like *.mydomain.com and it works.  But the problem is that we want users to also be able to go to just mydomain.com and have the site come up.  When I have the hostName configured as *.mydomain.com this apparently is not possible.

Any ideas?  The Sitecore developer network doesn't say too much on this (unless it's hidden somewhere I couldn't find).

Craig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try no dot in the `hostName`:

```
<site hostName="*mydomain.com" ... />
```

Answer (score 17):

For a bit more precision than Mark's removing the dot (which will work) you can use pipe separation to list alternative names:

```
<site hostName="mydomain.com | *.mydomain.com" ... />
```

That would allow you to configure a second site `reallymydomain.com` without it being caught by the hostName above. Remember the sites list will be processed in order, so the first match counts even if there's a second match that is more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip, James.  Much appreciated.  Can I ask where you learned this?  I was having a hard time finding documentation on it.

Comment: Saw it in a web.config I was working on. Not seen any documentation on it.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. We also use the hostName="site1.com|site2.com" notation in alot of our projects.

Comment: I noticed that the web.config also has a comment by default, which describes the use of the pipe character to separate multiple domains.

Answer (score 6):

Both Mark and James answers are correct and will help you resolve multiple domain/subdomain names to a single Sitecore site.

You may instead want to consider setting up a redirect in IIS from the non www domain to the www sub-domain or vice-versa.  Having more than one definitive URL for your domain can negatively effect your page rank.

This is a handy module for IIS 7 to help you define redirects.  http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite